# Kusto SCAN makes me crazy

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

could someone explain this!?

```
range i from 1 to 3 step 1
| scan with_match_id=matchId declare (s: long, n: long=0) with 
(
  step s1: true => s=1, n=s1.n + 1;
  step s2: true => s=2, n=s2.n + 1;
)
```

Output

| i | s | n | matchId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

Why is the first row (i=1) not matched by s2?
Why is n always 1?

That SCAN Operator makes me totally crazy. With one step it's more or less understandable, but with more than one step, I don't get it...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm still going crazy...yesterday there was an answer on this with some good explanation. Today the answer isn't visible anymore...any chance to see the deleted answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

Steps are always executed in their definition order.
We always start with the 1st step (*s1*) and then move to the 2nd, the 3rs etc. (note that a step might repeat itself multiple times).
By this definition, the 1st input line might match the 1st step, however, it cannot match any other step.

2.
*n* is always 1 because each step is matched only once.

In step *s1* you are refering to *s1.n*.
*s1.n* is the previous value of *s1*.
It has a value only if you execute this step multiple time.
Since you don't, the value take is the default value you have defined when you declared *n*, which is *0* (`n: long=0`).

Same thing for step *s2*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David! Makes it a little bit clearer to me. But honestly I didn't understand it completely ;-)
So why is s3_i always blank?  
Why is s1_1 for step==1 always always blank? (If there is only one step, s1_i is incremented starting from line 2)

Comment: Forgot to populate s3_i (answered updated) :-) As you can see it is still empty. The reason is very simple. Steps 1, 2 & 3 are the Turing machine states. We move from 1 to 2, to 3. There is no situation where our previous state is 3. Similarly, when we are on state/step 1, there is no previous state 1.